# simple for loop help needed in php

Tags: php

I have 568 rows in my csv file and my for loop looks like this

```
$csv = array();
$file = fopen('names.csv', 'r');

while (($result = fgetcsv($file)) !== false)
{
    $csv[] = $result;
}

fclose($file);

for ($row = 0; $row < 568; $row++)
{
echo "Serial no:<br/>";
echo "Name:".$csv[$row][1]."";
}
```

I want the output like this...

```
Serial no: 1
Name: Blah blah 1
Serial no: 2
Name: Blah blah 2
............
............
Serial no: 10
Name: Blah blah 10
```

For each 10 rows i want serial 1 to 10.. Once it finished 10 rows i want a horizontal line..

I mean i want to print

```
echo "<hr>";
```

For every 10 rows..

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: don't hardcode the number of lines.. also, the `$csv` array is not necessary, you can directly process the lines in the `while` loop...

Comment: I would not employ you as you asked a trival question.

Comment: @EdHeal Whats the point of commenting here when you have no intention in helping me? Stackoverflow not only filled with genius like you but also filled with noobs like me.. And its really weird you behave like this even though you have good reputation.. And i bet you are the one who given me down vote for my question. I hope you are satisfied.

Comment: @user1091558 - why not use the grey matter before hand?

Comment: @EdHeal why didn't you use that before commenting my question?

Comment: I gujess im am lazy @user1091558. Just like you. Cannot be bothered to find a username. At least I managed to fill in that part of the on-line form.

Comment: @EdHeal could you please stop this nonsense? You should have just asked sorry. There is more dignity in it. Instead you are just talking about my username which is irrelevant..

Comment: @user1091558 - Yes it is reverent.

Comment: @EdHeal You just started to getting on my nerves.. you are just an idiot who having fun by interfering other people's business.. So obviously I wasted my time by commenting here.  I hope you had pleasure by irritating me. Now GTFO..  And never answer or comment in my question.. You are not welcome..

Comment: @user1091558 - though - guess a public forum is not for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work :

```
for ($row = 0; $row < 568; $row++) {
    echo "Serial no:<br/>";
    echo "Name:".$csv[$row][1];
    echo (($row+1)%10 == 0) ? '<hr>' : '<br />';
}
```

Explanation :

- You don't need that ."" at the end of your "Name" line.
- $row + 1 : instead of $row to avoid printing an <hr> after the first element (pos 0)
- echo (condition) ? res1 : res 2; is like if (condition) echo res1; else echo res2;

But the real good way to do this would be :

```
$file = fopen('names.csv', 'r');
$i = 1;

while (($result = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
    echo "Serial no:" .$i. "<br/>";
    echo "Name:".$result[1];
    echo ($i == 1) ? '<hr>' : '<br />';
    $i = ($i%10)+1;
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: Hello Jerska.. Your code printing serial number from 1 to till the end. But i want serial numbers from 1 to 10.. I mean instead of 11 it should start from 1 again. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: The edit should work. But you know what ? That's supposed to be your part of the job, just a bit of reflexion would have given you the answer. Don't expect people to do the work for you every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$csv = array();
$file = fopen('names.csv', 'r');

while (($result = fgetcsv($file)) !== false)
{
    $csv[] = $result;
}

fclose($file);

for ($row = 0; $row < 568; $row++)
{
echo "Serial no:<br/>";
echo "Name:".$csv[$row][1]."";
   if ((int) $row % 10 === 0)
    {
        echo '<hr>';
    } 
}
```

Should do the trick :)

Comment: Hi thanks it solved the horizontal line problem. But i still need serial number.. I mean i want to print serial numbers from 1 to 10 for every 10 rows. can you help me for that?

Comment: See my answer I added the serial number and showed you the real good way to do what you want instead of using a temporary array.